# Get a value from database using PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I read few topics about my issue here and it didnt solve anything..

I don't understand where I am wrong in my code..

So I need to get the name from a database when my vt_id equal a number..

```
function recup_nom_visite($VT_ID){

        $pdo = PDO2::getInstance();

        $requete = $pdo->query("SELECT VT_NOM FROM CRF_VISITE WHERE VT_ID = :vt_id ");
        $requete->bindValue(':vt_id' , $VT_ID);
        $requete->execute();

            if($result = $requete->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $requete->closeCursor();
                return $result['NOM_VISITE'];
            }
        return false;
}
```

I tried this too :

```
function recup_nom_visite($VT_ID){

        $pdo = PDO2::getInstance();

        $requete = $pdo->query("SELECT VT_NOM FROM CRF_VISITE WHERE VT_ID ='".$VT_ID."' ");

            $req = $requete->fetch();
            $result = $req;
            return $result;
}
```

but all result it returns is "array" or nothing..

Do I miss something ?

Thank you for help

Comment: What is `'NOM_VISITE` ?

Comment: var where my result value get into normally

I did exactly the same code just above for get pa_inclusion ( its a value ) and it works but not this one.

Comment: `WHERE VT_ID  = :vt_id` forget `=` !!

Comment: yes sorry my bad in the draft but there is = in my code

Comment: You should use `$req['VT_NOM']`

Comment: you saved my life thank you Harshit 
I didn't know i had to use the same name as the select !

Answer (score 0):

```
function recup_nom_visite($VT_ID){
    $sql = "SELECT VT_NOM FROM CRF_VISITE WHERE VT_ID = ?";
    $stmt = PDO2::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($VT_ID));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

This is how PDO intended to work.

PS. Do not delete your questions. Deleted question cannot be answered, you know.